# How many google's admob Banner Ads can be in single mobile screen

Tags: admob, banner-ads

I have implemented google's Admob banner ads in my app. I tried this for that

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()

            // Add a test device to show Test Ads
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).addTestDevice("")
            .build();

    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

I want to know number of banner ads i can show so that policy don't get conflict.

Answer (score 4):

As you can read [here](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en)

the allowed number of banners per page is one.

[image]

Comment: also, I can suggest you to `AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()` when your view loads (so just one time), and then `mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);` when you want to show the ad.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. i dont know how to accept answer though i tried to upvote but i dont have that much reputation.

Comment: to accept the answer you have to click here on the button as shown in this picture http://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png

Comment: This "number of ads per page" has been removed by Google. Does it mean there is no more limit now?

Comment: Regarding the removal of "number of ads per page": https://marketingland.com/google-removes-adsense-3-ads-per-page-limit-focuses-content-ad-balance-189064